# How to send an SMS in a language other than English with module SIM800L?

Tags: c++, at-command, arduino-ide, sim800, sim800l

How to send a text message in Polish, e.g. with the following text "Cześć", where the characters are from outside the GSM alphabet? I have a TTGO T-Call board that has a SIM800L module from SIMCOM. I have tried using various AT commands, but nothing works. Has anyone encountered a similar problem? Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: https://forum.arduino.cc/t/sending-characters-in-different-languages-in-a-sim800l-module/511299

Answer (score 0):

According to the GSM specification 3GP TS 127.007, the magic command to declare that you want to send UCS2 characters (16 bits unicode) is:

```
AT+CSCS="UCS2"
```

From that point you must send the hex values of the unicode characters. The example says that to send `Abc` you actually send 004100620063. So to send `Cześć` it would be `0043007a0065015b0107`

Answer (score -1):

This is the working code for TTGO T-CALL 1.3/1.4 SIM800L

```
#define SIM800L_RX     27
#define SIM800L_TX     26
#define SIM800L_PWRKEY 4
#define SIM800L_RST    5
#define SIM800L_POWER  23

void Send_AT(String command) {
  Serial.println("AT: " + command);
  Serial2.println(command);
  long timer = millis();
  while (timer + 3000 > millis()) {
    while (Serial2.available()) {
      Serial.write(Serial2.read());
    }
  }
  Serial.println();
}

void setup() {
  pinMode(SIM800L_POWER, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(SIM800L_POWER, HIGH);
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial2.begin(9600, SERIAL_8N1, SIM800L_TX, SIM800L_RX);
  delay(1000);
  Serial.println("--- Loading Firmware ---\n");
  delay(5000);
  Serial.println("--- (C) 2022 by Dawid Irzyk ---");
  Serial.println("");
  while (Serial2.available()) {
    Serial.write(Serial2.read());
  }
}

void SendMessage()
{
  Serial2.print("ATZ\r\n");
  delay(2000);
  Serial2.print("AT+CSCS=\"HEX\"\r\n");
  delay(2000);
  Serial2.print("AT+CSMP=17,168,0,8\r\n");
  delay(2000);
  Serial2.print("AT+CMGF=1\r\n");
  delay(2000);
  Serial2.print("AT+CMGS=\"+48123123123\"\r\n");
  delay(2000);
  Serial2.print("0043007a0065015b0107");
  delay(2000);
  Serial2.println((char)26);
}

void loop() {

  SendMessage();

  while (true) {
    delay(1000);
  }
}
```